# Referencing jar from jre in buildpath

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I'm using Eclipse, and I'm developing a simple applet that's demonstrating usage of cookies.

In order to use cookies, I had to add "plugin.jar" to my build path. Now, that jar file is:

1. big (1.7 MB)
2. already present in my jre folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib)

Is there a way to use that plugin.jar in my project, but without need to add it to my build path, rather "point to it" in the jre folder (user anyway has to have jre in order to run applet)?

Comment: You can add external jar references to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a jar in jre/lib does not help, you should put it in `jre\lib\ext` instead.

Or you can place it anywere and change JRE config in Eclipse as follows

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Choose JRE -> Edit -> Add External Jar
```

Comment: Doing so gives me "Access restriction: The type PersistenceService is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\javaws.jar"